# Sometimes I get the exception "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'." Why

Tags: asp.net, soap, soap-client

I am trying to configure a WCF server\client to work with SSL but sometimes I get the following exception and sometimes don't for same data.

**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: have you recently installed the KB 931125 update?